Approximating shortest paths on weighted directed graphs
I have recently come across the paper Fast 2-Approximate All-Pairs Shortest Paths.
The authors state, in pg.1 of the introduction, that, given a directed, weighted graph, approximating the distances between any two vertices (that is, approximating APSP) requires $\Omega\left( n^\omega\right)$ time, but I'm having a hard time seeing how this can be stated for any approximation ratio? Or perhaps the vital question I'm missing out here is: Why is the directed case so much hard than the undirected one? What makes it so difficult?
I would not expect there to be any major difference, as Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, Johnson, etc, all work with the same runtime both for the directed and undirected case. I would assume any approximation algorithm will invoke one of those on smaller parts of the graph, or on some subset of vertices, approximating the distances through them.
